# MYSQL GROUP BY returns no results with FULLTEXT SEARCH

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, full-text-indexing

I have the following MYSQL schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
   `id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `tag` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
   FULLTEXT INDEX(`tag`),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tag`(`id`,`tag`) VALUES
('1','motor'),
('2','motor');
```

I want to select rows from `tag` table grouped by `tag` column. I ran the following command:

```
SELECT COUNT(id),tag FROM tag
GROUP BY tag
```

The expected result:

```
COUNT(id) | tag
------------------
    2     | motor
```

The actual result:
`no rows returned`

If I remove the `FullText` Index from the table, the results return as expected. I don't know what is going wrong when using `fulltext` with `group`

**Update** With further research the problem seems to be from the composite primary key. If I switch to one-column primary key, query works again but I need to use a composite key for this table as the same id could have multiple tags.

I created an SQL fiddle for you to try:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f765d/1/0

Comment: it was strange. bcuz it works fine by id

Comment: Hey,

i think it is not possible to use a fulltext key to group by on.
Specify your tag field as normal key seperatly, then it will work. Look at the execution plan, he tries to do the group by with the fulltext key. I don't think that this will be possible :P

Comment: Fulltext should be just a key for indexing. It should have nothing to do with grouping. The main problem is with the composite primary key. If I have just a primary id key, the fulltext would work with grouping. So the combination of composite key + fulltext + group on is not working for a reason that I need to know. Thanks

Comment: If you don't use it in the primary, he isn't using the fulltext key in the execution plan. So it's something like that.

Comment: @Demigod You gave me the hint. THANKS VERY MUCH!

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Probably a variation of [Fulltext index on a given column causes empty set for 'distinct' query](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79497).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that...the problem is that MYSQL is not using any of the 2 indices (primary and fulltext) so it returns no results. To solve this, we have to force MYSQL to use a certain index like in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: However, as you said, it's very likely a bug as MYSQL should use any of the indices instead of not executing at all!

Comment: Michael, just for clarification: an index influences how (fast) the db can execute a query, but not the resultset (that is considered unordered and unlimited). Try e.g. any query on a table without any indexes. Or try your query with the same indexes and data, but use a MyISAM table (replace ENGINE=InnoDB with ENGINE=MyISAM), which should not be affected by this bug. Forcing a different index here seems to be a workaround that prevents mysql from reaching the situation that results in the bug, but might give you the wrong impression how indexes work.

Comment: @Solarflare Thanks for clarification. You are right, this is not the use of `force index` as MYSQL is supposed to execute a query anyway even without index at all. This is just a hack around the bug still not fixed since 2015. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered the problem. The engine has 2 indices to choose from when executing the query, which ends up not using any at all and returning no results.

It's very likely that is a bug. This is a case where `FORCE INDEX` comes in handy as a workaround.

So the final working command:

```
SELECT COUNT(id),tag FROM tag
FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY)
GROUP BY tag
```

And this is a fiddle with the updated code:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8568/21/0

Thanks everyone!